# How to run code on every CPU

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, multicore, cpu-registers

I am trying to set the Performance Monitor User Mode Enable register on all cpus on a Nexus 4 running a mako kernel.

Right now I am setting the registers in a loadable module:

```
    void enable_registers(void* info)
    {
        unsigned int set = 1;
        /* enable user-mode access to the performance counter*/
        asm volatile ("mcr p15,  0, %0, c9,  c14, 0\n\t" : : "r" (set));
    }

    int init_module(void)
    {
       online = num_online_cpus();
       possible = num_possible_cpus();
       present = num_present_cpus();
       printk (KERN_INFO "Online Cpus=%d\nPossible Cpus=%d\nPresent Cpus=%d\n", online, possible, present);
       on_each_cpu(enable_registers , NULL, 1);
       return 0;
    }
```

The problem is that on_each_cpu only runs the function on Online cpus and as shown by the printk statment:

```
Online Cpus=1
Possible Cpus=4
Present Cpus=4
```

Only one of the four is online when I call on_each_cpu. So my question is, how do I force a cpu to be online, or how can force a certain cpu to execute code?
Thanks

Comment: you should start with "multithreaded programming" or otherwise called "concurrency", depending on what you are aiming at, but the core it's always the same, under Android you got the posix thread library to do all the low level routines, just like any other GNU/Linux distribution.

Comment: "So my question is, how do I force a cpu to be online, or how can force a certain cpu to execute code?" -- I am not aware that this is possible, as the chipset can and will power down cores as it sees fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to run the code on every cpu **right now**. What you need to do is arrange so that when the offline cpus come back online, your code is able to execute and enable the access to the PMU.

One way to achieve that would be with a cpu hotplug notifier.

Comment: For anyone else who tries to do this almost everything you need to know is here: "https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-hotplug.txt". I had to change the declaration of init_module to "int __cpuinit init_module(void)" to get the module to compile.

Comment: Eric, that link is now dead.

Comment: In case it goes dead, the jist of what I had to do is:
`#include <linux/cpu.h>
 static int foobar_cpu_callback(struct notifier_block *nfb,
           unsigned long action, void *hcpu)
 {
  unsigned int cpu = (unsigned long)hcpu;

  switch (action) {
  case CPU_ONLINE:
                     smp_call_function_single(cpu, &enable_registers, NULL, false)
  }
  return NOTIFY_OK;
 }

 static struct notifier_block foobar_cpu_notifier =
 {
    .notifier_call = foobar_cpu_callback,
 };`

Comment: Also init the cpu notifier:
You need to call register_cpu_notifier() from your init function.
Init functions could be of two types:
1. early init (init function called when only the boot processor is online).
2. late init (init function called _after_ all the CPUs are online).

For the first case, you should add the following to your init function

 register_cpu_notifier(&foobar_cpu_notifier);

For the second case, you should add the following to your init function

 register_hotcpu_notifier(&foobar_cpu_notifier);