# How to execute a piece of kernel code on all CPUs?

Tags: linux-kernel, multiprocessing, msr

I'm trying to make a kernel module to enable FOP compatibility mode for x87 FPU. This is done via setting bit 2 in `IA32_MISC_ENABLE` MSR. Here's the code:

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <asm/msr-index.h>
#include <asm/msr.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("10110111");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Module to enable FOPcode compatibility mode");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");

static int __init fopCompat_init(void)
{
   unsigned long long misc_enable=native_read_msr(MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE);
   printk(KERN_INFO "Before trying to set FOP_COMPAT, IA32_MISC_ENABLE=%llx,"
                    " i.e. FOP_COMPAT is %senabled\n"
                    ,misc_enable,misc_enable&MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE_X87_COMPAT?"":"NOT ");

   wrmsrl(MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE,misc_enable|MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE_X87_COMPAT);
   misc_enable=native_read_msr(MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE);

   printk(KERN_INFO "Tried to set FOP_COMPAT. Result: IA32_MISC_ENABLE=%llx,"
                    " i.e. FOP_COMPAT is now %senabled\n"
                    ,misc_enable,misc_enable&MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE_X87_COMPAT?"":"NOT ");
   return 0;
}

static void __exit fopCompat_exit(void)
{
   const unsigned long long misc_enable=native_read_msr(MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE);
   printk(KERN_INFO "Quitting FOP-compat with IA32_MISC_ENABLE=%llx\n",misc_enable);
   if(!(misc_enable & MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE_X87_COMPAT))
       printk(KERN_INFO "NOTE: seems some CPUs still have to be set up, "
                        "or compatibility mode will work inconsistently\n");
   printk(KERN_INFO "\n");
}

module_init(fopCompat_init);
module_exit(fopCompat_exit);
```

It seems to work, but on multiple `insmod/rmmod` cycles I sometimes get `dmesg` output that the compatibility mode wasn't still enabled, although it was immediately after doing `wrmsr`. After some thinking I realized that it's because the module code was executed on different logical CPUs (I have Core i7 with 4 cores*HT=8 logical CPUs), so I had a 1/8 chance of getting "enabled" print on doing `rmmod`. After repeating the cycle for about 20 times I got consistent "enabled" prints, and my userspace application happily works with it.

So now my question is: how can I make my code execute on all logical CPUs present on the system, so as to enable compatibility mode for all of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For execute code on every CPU use `on_each_cpu` function.

Signature:

```
int on_each_cpu(void (*func) (void *info), void *info, int wait)
```

Description:

> Call a function on all processors.

If `wait` parameter is non-zero, it waits for function's completion on all CPUs.

Function `func` shouldn't sleep, but whole `on_each_cpu()` call shouldn't be done in atomic context.

Comment: Are there any limitation as to when you can use it? Meaning at which point in the kernel init, after and before which function has run?

Comment: I don't know exactly. I think, after kernel threading subsystem is initialized, the function becomes usable.

Comment: Im facing a weird problem where the function on runs on cpu0 for some reason, any ideas?

Comment: I don't know. You may create new question post, and provide description of the problem in it.

Comment: It could be that all of the cpus aren't online yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456812/how-to-run-code-on-every-cpu